# What is the difference between pubKey and PubKeyPEM?

Tags: python, encryption

I am learning the `RSA` encryption algorithm, and I want to use that in Python. I'm using the `pycryptodome` package, and I can see from [there](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/asymmetric-key-ciphers/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-examples) that there are two private keys variables.

What is the difference between `pubKey` and `pubKeyPEM`, and which of them I need to use for the encryption part?

Also, why the `Decryptor` use both of the keys (`keyPair`) instead of the private key (`privKeyPEM`) ?

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

keyPair = RSA.generate(1024)

pubKey = keyPair.publickey()
pubKeyPEM = pubKey.exportKey()

privKeyPEM = keyPair.exportKey()

Encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pubKey)
Decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(keyPair)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pubKey` is just the presentation of the key as usable by Python. It consists of two integers: the modulus and the public exponent. Of course, it could e.g. also be a reference to a key in a hardware device, where applicable.

`pubKeyPEM` is a specific encoding of the public key in bytes or characters. It's a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure according [to the API specifications](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey). `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` or SPKI is a binary structure, PEM is an ASCII armor around that, i.e. it specifies the structure and then encodes the binary using base 64. It's commonly used by e.g. OpenSSL.

For the encryption part you need the `pubKey`. But you probably have to transport the `pubKey` to the sender first, or you may have to store the `pubKey` in a DB or filesystem. That's where the export functionality comes in.

The private key generally contains the public key (as public exponent field), or it is easy to calculate it from the private key (in case of an Elliptic Curve key). So you might as well think of the private key as the key pair. It depends on the library if the concepts can be used interchangeably.

Comment: PS note that the export function assumes `pkcs=1` as default parameter, and then exports a SubjectPublicKeyIdentifier. This is a bit ironic as PKCS#1 specifies a different public key format with less information; the SPKI **contains** the PKCS#1 formatted public key, but they are not directly compatible. That's an API design mistake if you ask me.